# Irreps of this algebra?

Tags: rt.representation-theory

Hello!

I stumbled upon the following commutative, non-associative, three-dimensional algebra (with basis $\{A, B, C\}$):

$A\times A = 0$
$A\times B = A$
$A\times C = 2B$
$B\times A = A$
$B\times B = B$
$B\times C = C$
$C\times A = 2B$
$C\times B = C$
$C\times C = 0$

Is anything known about its irreducible representations? In particular, how many nonequivalent irreps do exist? What are their dimensions? Can we construct explicit representation matrices for a given irrep?

Comment: Algebra over what ring? How exactly is "representation" defined if the algebra is non-associative?
First observation: The algebra is commutative and $B$ is its neutral element.

Comment: Second observation: If you make this associative, then $0 = A^2 C^2 = A(2B)C=2AC=4B$. Since $B$ is the multiplicative identity, this means that $4x=0$ for any x in your ring. If you don't make it associative, then I don't know what you mean by a representation.

Comment: More over, in an associative version $0=AAC=A2B=2A$ holds. Since $\lbrace A,B,C\rbrace$ is assumed to be a basis, the characteristic must be two. Therefore the algebra is just $R[A,C]/(A^2,AC,C^2)$ with whatever base ring $R$ is choosen to be. The simple modules of this are just the simple $R$-modules with $A$ and $C$ acting as zero.

Comment: To summarize the above comments: there is no (sensible) notion of representation for non-associative algebras, and therefore your questions doesn't make sense.

Comment: I believe there is a notion of module over an algebra over an operad, or something along those lines, and I believe that specializing that definition to this case gives the following: if $A$ is a non-associative algebra (a magma internal to the category of $k$-vector spaces for some field $k$), then an $A$-module is a $k$-vector space $M$ equipped with a bilinear map $A \times M \to M$ satisfying... no axioms! Not a very interesting thing. 

Comment: Alternatively, one could go the other way, and consider the operad of *all* relations satisfied by this particular algebra, and use that. SOmeone ought to voluteer tofind all identities, though! :)

Comment: There are few approaches to construct general theory of representation of algebras within arbitrary varieties. One of them - pretty straightford one - is to consider extensions of an algebra by square-zero algebra, see, for example, S. Eilenberg, Extensions of general algebras, Ann. Soc. Polon. Math. 21 (1948), 125-134. I believe something along these lines is contained also in some paper(s) of Gerstenhaber. But, indeed, this does not seem to lead to some interesting theories or examples, except the well-established associative, Lie and Jordan (and perhaps, alternative, to some degree) cases.

Answer (score 6):

Your algebra is a Jordan algebra.

Armed with Jacobson's *Structure and representations of Jordan algebras*, for example, you will be able to find the sensible notion of representation of your algebra (there are, in fact, a couple of sensible notions...) Using that, and since the algebra is of dimension $3$, which is hopefully small, one can possibly describe the irreducible ones.

Of course, this is more or less arbitrary: you have to choose in what sense you want to represent your algebra—this is what the comments above are hinting at—but, well, looking at it as a Jordan algebra makes this choice for you.

Comment: A representation of a Jordan algebra $(\mathbb J,\cdot)$ is a map $\rho:\mathbb J\to \mathrm{End}(V)$ such that $\rho(A\cdot B)=\rho(A)\rho(B)+\rho(B)\rho(A)$ for any $A,B\in \mathbb J$. Another option is to require the map $\rho$ to land in the subset of self-adjoint operators.